# Switch to English version of Adobe Web Premium CS 5.5

Tags: cs5

On the compact disk I received for Adobe Web Premium Creative Suite version 5.5, there was only a German version of the tools.

Is it possible to uninstall the CS and use the English version, which I can download [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/de/creative-suite/kb/cs5-product-downloads.html) with my license key, or is it bound to a specific language?

I have a student license on Windows 7 (32) Bit.

Comment: From the Adobe support site: "If your serial number is for a different language set than the installation language, you get this error message ['The serial number is not valid for this product']."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my similar experience with CS4 is true for CS5.5 as well, then you are out of luck. You decide the language the software is in when you buy it, and you can't switch around.

Comment: I was able to switch the language by adding some older language files, from CS 4, unfortunately not all is translated, but its better than before now. But this should not be the way to go. :( Thanks for your help anyways.